# How to combine 4 tables using subquery SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a table which consists of 4 tables: `clients`, `groups_clients`, `client_data1`, `client_data2`;

**clients**

```
clId| GroupId  | Other |
------------------------
 1  | 1        | gddgdg|
 2  | 1        | dgdg  |
 3  | 2        | ddg   |
 4  | 2        | dd4g  |
 5  | 1        | ddg   |
```

**groups_clients**

```
 grId | GroupName| 
 -----------------
   1  | Group1   |
   2  | Group2   |
```

**table_data1**

```
 clId | Date       | Buy  | Trade |
  --------------------------------
   1  | 2017-06-05 | 3    | 4     |
   2  | 2017-11-10 | 6    | 9     |
   2  | 2017-11-11 | 4    | 13    | 
   2  | 2017-03-01 | 11   | 0     |  
   4  | 2017-01-10 | 3    | 11    |
```

**table_data2**

```
 clId | Date       | With | Depos |
  --------------------------------
   1  | 2017-03-05 | 1    | 3     |
   5  | 2017-08-10 | 0    | 8     |
   2  | 2017-11-11 | 0    | 13    | 
   3  | 2017-03-01 | 11   | 0     |  
   4  | 2017-01-10 | 3    | 11    |
```

The desirable table should be like this

```
GroupName | SUM(Buy) | SUM(Trade) | SUM(With) | SUM(Depos) |
------------------------------------------------------------
  Group1  | 13       | 26         | 1         | 24         |
  Group2  | 3        | 11         | 14        | 11         |
```

The query should sum all the rows taken from `table_data1` and taken `table_data2` where date is `some date` and group it by `group name`

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
    groups_clients.GroupName as group_name, 
    clients.GroupId AS groupid, 
    SUM(table_data1.buy) AS buy, 
    SUM(table_data1.trade) AS trade, 
    with,
    depos
FROM 
    table_data1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(table_data2.with) AS with, 
         clients.clId, GroupId 
     FROM 
         clients 
     LEFT JOIN 
         table_data2 ON clients.clId = table_data2.clId 
                     AND table_data2.date <= '11-11-2016' 
     GROUP BY 
         GroupId, clId) clients ON table_data1.clId = clients.clId 
LEFT JOIN 
    groups_clients ON groups_clients.Id = clients.GroupId 
WHERE 
    table_data1.date <= '11-11-2016'
GROUP BY 
    clients.GroupId, With, Depos, 
    groups_clients.GroupName
```

But the result is kinda terrible. It outputs a lot of the same groups in a row, seems like I haven't grouped by `groupname`. So...I need your help, guys. Any ideas? What am I supposed to do to make it query work right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pre-group the SUMS and then join to avoid double counting rows.

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate='11/11/2017'

SELECT gc.GroupName, 
        isnull(SUM([Buy]), 0) [Buy], 
        isnull(SUM([Trade]), 0) [Trade], 
        isnull(SUM([With]), 0) [With], 
        isnull(SUM([Depos]), 0) [Depos]
FROM groups_clients gc
    INNER JOIN clients c ON gc.grId=c.GroupId
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT clId, SUM([Buy]) [Buy], SUM([Trade])[Trade]
        FROM table_data1 WHERE [Date]=@mydate GROUP BY clId) a ON c.clId=a.clId
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT clId, SUM([With]) [With], SUM([Depos])[Depos] 
        FROM table_data2 WHERE [Date]=@mydate GROUP BY clId) b ON c.clId=b.clId
GROUP BY gc.GroupName
```

Comment: But, what about a groupname? Where should I group it using your code, ma'am?

Comment: I caught many errors about invalid column names in subqueries

Comment: I assume it's because you have a column named `With` which is a keyword.  I added the [] to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting from the group_client table.. join to clients and then to table_data1 and table_data2.. and then aggregate the columns you want?

So the query would go something like this

```
declare @date date = '2017-06-05'

select 

gc.groupname 
,sum(td1.buy) as total_buy
,sum(td1.Trade) as total_trade
,sum(td2.with) as total_with
,sum(td2.Depos) as total_depos

from groups_client gc

    inner join clients c
        on c.groupid = gc.grid

    inner join table_data1 td1
        on td1.clid = c.clid
        and td1.Date = @date

    inner join table_data2 td2
        on td2.clid = c.clid
        and td2.Date = @date

        group by 

        gc.groupname
```

Comment: No, but I'm gonna try

Comment: It works, but counted numbers are too big. Looks like it goes in a circle loop and sums many times the same values. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Harry, this query is falling afoul of what's known as a cartesian product.  Run the query without the `GROUP BY` clause and see if you can spot what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry.. it was something to try.. Indiris answer below should work better I guess.. I wrote the query on the fly without really testing it..